# Calling Blender from PHP/Python and Blender doesn't open

Tags: python, error

The code below is a simplified version of the process I am creating. On my local machine this process works fine, but on my companies server, it does not work. It will time out. One thing to note, when I look in the server task manager (Windows), Blender will start as a background process, but not active. In my regular process, Blender will render a file , but that does not happen in my full process. After the call to Blender, it never finishes. Below is a simplified version of my process.

Form to enter information

```
<!doctype html>
<body>

<form action="dosomething.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="some number" id="time">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP to take values and pass to python

```
<!doctype html>
<body>

<?php

$outputDir = "output/";
$outputDirFull = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/output/';
$errorDir = "error/";

//move spaces to all spaces in blender path; will be removed in CallBlender.py; necessary to pass to python
$blenderWithSpaces = 'C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender/blender.exe';
$blender = str_replace(" ","#",$blenderWithSpaces);
$blenderFile = 'blenderfile/test.blend';

$blenderScript = 'pythonfile/testscript.py';

//Specify python and CallBlender.py
$python = "C:/Users/Render/Anaconda3/python.exe";
$pyscript = "pythonfile/CallBlender.py";


$time = $_POST["time"];

//creating the command, and passing time and efficiency; spaces are kept in command because the quotes
$command ="$python $pyscript $time $blender $blenderFile $blenderScript $outputDirFull 2>&1";

//executing the command to call processing python program
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Python to call blender

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

testfile = 'output/output.txt'

#read in values from PHP
time = sys.argv[1]
blender = sys.argv[2]
blenderFile = sys.argv[3]
blenderScript = sys.argv[4]
outputDirFull = sys.argv[5]

# remove pound sign from blender path and replace spaces
blender = str(blender.replace('#',' '))

with open(testfile, 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(time))

#Below is the command to call Blender and run the blender file
command = blender + ' ' + blenderFile + ' -P ' + blenderScript + ' -- ' + time + ' ' + outputDirFull
subprocess.call(command)
```

Here is a snippet of the blender python script

```
import bpy
import math
import sys
from os.path import join

# try to read the path passed from BlastParse.php

argv = sys.argv
argv = sys.argvargv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] # get all args after "--"

Time = str(argv[0])

efficiency = '85'

outputDirFull = str(argv[1])

sys.exit()
```

Comment: Forget all the php stuff, have you tried running blender manually on the server? or running your python script manually? Do you see anything log messages when you do this?

Comment: Yes. If I run the python script from the terminal and hardcode all the values into the python script before the call, blender opens and runs correctly.

Comment: So to reiterate, passing values from my python script to blender seems to work just fine. The issue seems to be when passing values from PHP to Python, THEN calling blender. I checked the values being passed from PHP to python (in case I had a typo) and they all look correct. This stumps me because a few weeks ago this process did not have an issue.