# Calling blender in PHP outputs nothing

Tags: python, command-line

I'm currently running a python script in my command line that uses blender:

```
blender -b -P script.py -- argument1
```

This works fine in my terminal however it returns no output in PHP when used

`exec("blender -b -P script.py -- argument1", $test);
echo implode($test);`

Commands such as "ls" work fine. It's only blender that doesn't want to run.

I saw [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136038/calling-blender-from-php-python-and-blender-doesnt-open) that is pretty much the exact same problem I'm facing. It has not been answered yet.

Comment: Have your checked if any errors are displayed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914402/php-exec-is-not-executing-the-command

Comment: After trying that I'm getting a lot of errors. They go along the lines of "No protocol specified xcb_connection_has_error() returned true"

Comment: That's strange because when trying the command in the command line (same directory) it works fine.

Comment: Are you running the PHP command locally or on remote server?

Comment: Locally. My site is also stored locally with xampp.

Comment: So you didn't run the PHP script from a local interpreter, but you webserver? Could be a permission problem. The full error message could help narrow it down. Your question is likely better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Alright, thanks.